# Count matched words from IN operator

Tags: mysql

i have this little mysql query :

```
select t.title FROM title t
inner join movie_keyword mk on mk.movie_id = t.id
inner join keyword k on k.id = mk.keyword_id
where k.keyword IN ( 
select k.keyword 
FROM title t
inner join movie_keyword mk on mk.movie_id = t.id
inner join keyword k on k.id = mk.keyword_id
where t.id = 166282 
) 
LIMIT 15
```

as you can see it will return all titles from `title` that have at least one the same keyword that have movie with id 166282.

Now i have problem, because i want also count how many keywords was matched in `IN` operator(let's say i want to see only titles that have 3 or more the same keywords), i tried something with aggregate functions, but everything failed, so i came here with my problem. Maybe somebody can give me some advice, or code example.

I'm not also sure, if this "subquery way" is good, so if there are some better options how i should solve my problem, I am open to any suggestions or tips.

Thank you!

@Edit

So after some problems, i have one more. This is my current query :

```
SELECT s.title,s.vote,s.rating,count(dk.key) as keywordCnt, count(dg.name) as genreCnt 

FROM series s 

INNER JOIN series_has_genre shg ON shg.series_id = s.id 
INNER JOIN dict_genre dg ON dg.id = shg.dict_genre_id

INNER JOIN series_has_keyword shk ON shk.series_id = s.id
INNER JOIN dict_keyword dk ON dk.id = shk.dict_keyword_id
WHERE dk.key IN (

SELECT dki.key FROM series si 
INNER JOIN series_has_keyword shki ON shki.series_id = si.id
INNER JOIN dict_keyword dki ON dki.id = shki.dict_keyword_id
WHERE si.title LIKE 'The Wire'

)

and dg.name IN (

SELECT dgo.name FROM series so 
INNER JOIN series_has_genre shgo ON shgo.series_id = so.id 
INNER JOIN dict_genre dgo ON dgo.id = shgo.dict_genre_id
WHERE so.title LIKE 'The Wire'

) 
and s.production_year > 2000
GROUP BY s.title
ORDER BY s.vote DESC, keywordCnt DESC ,s.rating DESC, genreCnt DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Problem is, it is very, very, very slow. Any tips what i should change, to run it faster ?

Comment: Can you please more elaborate your query?

Comment: @Nazmul Sorry, but i'm not sure if i understand you. The query from my first post is all i have now, and it's the only example that is working now.

Comment: See CASE, as in `SUM(CASE WHEN x IN('a','b','c') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) n`

Comment: I mean, please explain your query.

Comment: @Nazmul I have 3 tables `title` `title_has_keyword` and `keyword`. I want to show TOP 15 titles that have the similiar keywords like title with id `166282`  for example. But of course each title have different keywords, so i want to count how many keywords were matched and sort them descending basing on keywords count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you:

```
select t.title, count(k.keyword) as keywordCount FROM title t
inner join movie_keyword mk on mk.movie_id = t.id
inner join keyword k on k.id = mk.keyword_id
where k.keyword IN ( 
    select ki.keyword 
    FROM title ti
    inner join movie_keyword mki on mki.movie_id = ti.id
    inner join keyword ki on ki.id = mki.keyword_id
    where ti.id = 166282 
) group by t.title 
LIMIT 15
```

Note that I have changed the table names inside the nested query to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you, it was really easier than i thought. Anyway it is working as i want, but is horrible slow.